# note cancelling or what is it called?

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music, ornaments

i came across a sign on my notation where a note is being played that is G after that there is a note in between e that is open but we first play it and then hammer on it... what is it called ?

[image: Small quaver with stroke through flag and stem]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called a grace note. Its duration can be stolen from either the note before or after it, depending on the stylistic context.  I think the slash is intended to indicate "as fast as possible".

Comment: This particular grace note is an acciaccatura, or crushed note. It is played very rapidly.

Comment: It is an acciaccatura, just one kind of 'grace note'. The idea is to play it and get off it as soon as possible. the word translates from Italian as 'crushing'. Hence on guitar, an immediate hammer-on is a nice simple way to perform it, and the following G.

Comment: That slash line isn't cancellation!

Comment: @ibonyun: I don't agree with the *as fast as possible* part. The note value (an eighth here) clearly indicates the intended length in relation to the main note.

Comment: @guidot I don't think the fact that the engraver used an 8th note has much to do with the actual intended duration of the grace note.  The precise duration of grace notes is a subject rife with debate, so I don't think there is a "correct" answer here.  Other commenters pointed out it is an acciaccatura -- because of the slash I think -- which in Old Brixtonian's words "is played very rapidly", and in Tim's words "play it and get off it as soon as possible".

Comment: @guidot the piano part in Schumann's *In der Fremde* (number 8 of *Liederkreis,* Opus 39) begins with a figure composed of seven sixteenth notes of which the second is decorated by an acciaccatura like the one here, an eighth note with a slash through it.  The fact that it's written with the form of an eighth note is definitely not supposed to indicate the duration of an eighth note.